# Why does the ag-grid repo track built files?

Tags: ag-grid

Out of curiosity, why does the [Ag-grid project](https://www.ag-grid.com/) (specifically it's [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/)), contain build/built files in version control?

As can be seen [here](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/tree/master/dist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the vast majority of users pull down releases of ag-Grid from NPM or Bower, there are some that prefer to pull the latest release directly from GitHub.

The files under the /dist directory represent the latest available release and only get updated when a release is done.

thanks

Comment: That's a poor reason in my opinion and is not worth the trouble/overhead it introduces when having to manage the source code. It put me off ag-grid completely.